# Вывод контента в зависимости от url

Tags: php, javascript

пользователь выбирает в фильтре значения и по соответствующим значения выдается результат, но не всегда значения совпадают с результатом и на данный момент нужно реализовать, если не совпадает значение то выдает >К сожалению по данному запросу ничего не найдено

Есть такого рода get запрос

```
/?filter_ширина=68&filter_высота=40&filter_диаметр=&filter_бренд=&filter_cезон=&filter_тип=
```

В котором отсутствует товар нужно вывести в контенте текст

> "К сожалению по данному запросу ничего не найдено"

и таких запросов несколько.

Comment: Если это `get` запрос, то парсите на сервере его, если не находит продуктов - возвращаете строку что не найдено. Принимаете ее и выводите где вам удобно с помощью `javascript`. А так из вашего вопроса ничего не ясно что у вас не получается, и что вы уже сделали чтобы получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Смотря что вас конкретно интересует ?

PHP:

```
if (!isset($_GET['tovar']) || empty($_GET['tovar'])) {
   redirect('404'); // пользователькая функция 
}
```

JS:

```
function parse(val) {
    var result = "Not found",
        tmp = [];
    location.search
    .substr(1)
        .split("&")
        .forEach(function (item) {
        tmp = item.split("=");
        if (tmp[0] === val) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
    });
    return result;
}
```

Где в `val` передается нужный параметр в зависимости от результата средиректите куда нужно `window.location.href = "http://ru.stackoverflow.com";` но лучше делать это на стороне сервера.

Comment: могли бы описать данный скрип, не совсем понимаю что куда

Comment: @IvanKling какой именно, и вернёмся к первому вопросу что конкретно вам нужно сделать, на стороне клиента реализовать проверку или на стороне сервера, что-то обработать должно ?

Comment: На стороне клиента, обрабатывает get запросы, пользователь выбирает в фильтре значения и по соответствующим значения выдается результат, но не всегда значения совпадают с результатом и на данный момент нужно реализовать, если не совпадает значение то выдает >К сожалению по данному запросу ничего не найдено